# deploy xamarin forms app on ipad of neighbour fails

Tags: xcode, debugging, xamarin.forms, deployment, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin forms app that crashes on old ipads.
Since I don't own an old ipad I asked my neighbour, who reported the error, if I could borrow his device to debug the problem. I can deploy to my own ipad / iphone without problems, but not to my neighbours Ipad.

**When I try to deploy i get the following error: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015**

Steps I took:

- removed the app from the ipad
- started xcode on my mac and opened 'window - devices and simulators'
- copied the device identifier of my neighbour's ipad and added it to my developer account on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list
- opened the provisioning profiles on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list
  and downloaded the one that is selected in my iOS project under Build - iOS Bundle Signing
- opened xcode and right mouse button on the ipad - show provisioning profiles. This list is empty for this ipad.
- i tried to load (plus sign) the downloaded provisioning profile onto the ipad but it wouldn't let me. (failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on the device)

Comment: What's your specific problem? Add the device UUID and download the new provisioning profile. Then you can use this provisioning profile in the XCode for deploying apps to that iPad.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, i fixed it while typing my problem. I still posted the question for people who might run in to the same issue and search for the error message (like my future self)

Comment: Ok, It would be better if you write the solution in the answer and mark it:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it.

The problem was that the provisioning profile i downloaded did not yet contain the device id of the ipad. I had to create a new provisioning profile and select the ipad to be added to the profile. (and then download the file and add it to the device through 'xcode - window - simulators and devices' like mentioned above)

pfff... if only this could have been done automatically.